# Kohana 3.3 ORM relationships - has_one

Tags: orm, php, kohana

Скажите, друзья, есть таблица users(id-PKEY). И я хочу сделать профайлы, для каждого пользователя (год, место рождения, интересы, и.тд). Предполагается, что каждому пользователю будет соответствовать одна запись (один профиль) с таблицы профайлы (profiles).

Скажите, как связать эти модели друг с другом?

```
Customuser.php
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
class Model_Customuser extends Model {
    protected $_table = 'user';
    protected $_has_one = array(
        'profiles' => array(
            'model' => 'Profile',
            'foreign_key' => 'user_id',
            ),
        );

}
```

Profile.php
    <?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

```
class Model_Profile extends ORM {

    protected $_has_one = array(
        'user' => array(
            'model' => 'Customuser',
            'foreign_key' => 'id',
            ),
        );

} // End
```

структуры таблиц :

```
| users | CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `logins` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_login` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

|profiles | CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `weight` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `city` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nickname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_profiles_user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |

На контроллере пытаюсь получить доступ к профайлу:
$user = ORM::factory('customuser',1);
$city = $user->profiles->city;
print $city;
```

В результате получаю ошибку: `Undefined property $profiles;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В версии 3.3 вам надо указывать имя модели с учетом регистра (*кроме некоторых случаев*). А значит:

$user = ORM::factory('Customuser',1);

Заметка. Не очень хорошая идея, называть связь `has_one` во множественном числе: `profiles`. Он же один - `profile`. Это раз.
Если в одной модели `has_one`, то во второй - `belongs_to`. [Различия](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/comment/15622#Comment_15622) в месте хранения ссылки. Это два.

Comment: абсолютно правы. все получилось. спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

`$_has_one` не загружает объект в модель! Вот так нужно:

```
$object->has_one_relation->find()->relation_property;
```

Comment: спасибо, значит здесь все таки не верно ? 
http://kohanaframework.su/database/orm_connections1

Comment: @kemerov4anin, в данном случае вы неправы. Для ``$_has_one`` не надо вызывать ``find()``. См. [код](https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/ORM.php#L653)

@Vfvtnjd, дампните свой ``$user`` и посмотрите, что там есть, а чего нет.